# Find gaussian in data

Tags: estimation, detection

I have some time series data (blue line lower plot) with a gaussian added into it (red line upper plot). I would like to estimate where the gaussian is in the data, and the height of the gaussian (these parameters can be bounded).

Is there an algorithm that can estimate and find where the gaussian is in the data (blue line, upper plot)?

Or a better question might be, is there a way I could come up with a probability curve for finding a gaussian in the data if I don't know what height or it's location (mean).

The model would be:

$$y(x)=A c_0 e^{-A c_0 \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{x_0}}$$
or
$$y(x)=\frac{A^2}{{(1+e^{-A c_0 \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{x_0}})}^2} c_0 e^{-A c_0 \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{x_0}}$$

[image]

Note: this is just a simulated gaussian, normally I have just the blue line in the upper plot.

Explanation of upper plot:
Red line, original data
Blue line, original data with gaussian added (the gaussian is in the lower plot has been added to the blue line in the upper plot)

I only have the blue line in the upper plot, I am trying to detect the location in the x direction of the gaussian (where it peaks parameter x_0) and maybe the height A

The gaussian is my signal, the blue line in the upper plot is my noise
the redline is an example of noise + gaussian and a typical time series that I work with.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your explanation of the charts.  If you are trying to find the best fit Gaussian in the difference of your blue and red graphs in the top chart, you merely have to take the natural log and find the best fit parabola.

Comment: do you have a model for the non-gaussian signal?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, but there should be some way to estimate if there is a gaussian shape in the data?

Comment: @CedronDawg I don't have the red data in the real world as physical processes sum the data, I need to separate them or at least detect if there is a gaussian in the signal somewhere of unknown amplitude

Comment: My apologies, I left the squared portion out

Comment: You are still going to have to provide a way better explanation.  The red line (what is that?) isn't Gaussian shaped either.  You have not explained at all the nature of those curves.  Finding the parameters of a parabola is pretty straightforward by applying a differential operator which will yield a line.   You can read the higher order parameters from the line, then all you have to solve for is the offset.  I could easily best fit a Gaussian to your blue curve.  Please take a step back and instead of trying to get details on a solution, provide a broader description of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When simulating data with a neat model, like in yours, there is a risk of bias in trying to recovered the "true" model from the observation, and overlooking some tacit assumptions or even the actual goal (hence this pragmatic answer).

First, fitting Gaussians to noisy data is a complicated topic, that as attracted many works. Even fitting a single Gaussian across an empirical histogram, and require some assumptions of the nature of the fluctuations. You can look for instance at [A Fast, Accurate, and Separable Method for Fitting a Gaussian Function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.07241.pdf), with reviews some classical algorithms (Caruana, Guo, Roonizi), deals with over-determination, additive or multiplicative noise, etc. More generally, assumption on the positivity, the nature of the residual, the scale of the Gaussian, because this can be ill-posed. Here the noise is mild, but the red line does not seem very smooth after tick 1200, and this could affect the fit.

There are many other approaches:

- perform a robust fit using some lose model on the background, with reparametrization (because the nonlinearity in amplitude, location or scale is disturbing),
- estimate directly a location and a scale parameter, because you are apparently more interested in those than in the full model. Here, the bump location could be detected with scale-space operators, and then the scale with robust second-order moment methods.